# My threading function doesn't stop the thread I want

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm trying to make a stopwatch class, which has an seperate thread that counts down.
The issue here is that when I use the cancel function or try setting up the stopwatch again after a timeout, my program crashes. At the moment I am sure it's due some threading issues, probably because of misuse. Is there anyone that can tell me why this doesn't work and can help me get it working?

```
 Stopwatch.h

 class Stopwatch
    {
    public:
        void Run(uint64_t ticks);
        void Set(uint64_t ms);
        void Cancel();

    private:
        std::thread mythread;
    };



Stopwatch.cpp

void Stopwatch::Run(uint64_t ticks)
{
  uint64_t clockCycles = ticks;

  while(clockCycles > 0){
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1));
    clockCycles--;
  }

  //do anything timeout related, probab a cout in the future
}

void Stopwatch::Set(uint64_t ms)
{
    mythread = std::thread(&Timer::Run, this, ms);
}

void Stopwatch::Cancel()
{
    mythread.join();
}
```

What I want is to call the stopwatch to set a time and get some timeout reaction. With the cancel function is can be stopped at any time. After that with the set function you can restart it.

Comment: The reason that your program crashes is not in the code that you have shown. It is probably in the code using the `Stopwatch` class. However: 1. `Cancel()` does not interrupt the thread, it waits for it to end by itself. 2. `std::this_thread::sleep_for` does not sleep for exactly the given time, but *at least* that. Your clock will be imprecise.

Comment: `join()` does not stop a thread. It waits until the thread stops. There is no way to terminate a thread, in C++. The only way a thread terminates is by returning from the initial thread function. If you want to terminate a thread in any other way, you will have to write the code to do that, by notifying the thread, somehow, that it needs to stop whatever it's doing, and terminate.

Comment: A started `std::thread` must be `join`ed (or `detach`ed) before it can be destroyed. This is true even if the thread function has since returned. In your case, it means that you may need to `join` in `Set` call, and in `Stopwatch` destructor. Use `std::thread::joinable()` to check whether a `join()` call is needed. And, as others said, `join()` actually blocks until the thread function returns - it does not instantly terminate that function as you seem to believe.

Comment: Why do you think you need the complexity of threads for something like a stopwatch? What's wrong with a FSM or using something like `select()` with a timeout or many other options? Using threads just complicated things.

Comment: I'm using a different thread because I am doing other things at the same time, waiting for the timeout of the stopwatch

Comment: @MrEmper "doing other things" does not mean you *have* to use threads. There are other ways that have been used for years, like -for example- State Machines.

Comment: So in order to make it quit I have to add return; at the end of the Run function?

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comments, you must always eventually call `join` or `detach` for a `std::thread` which is joinable (i.e., has or had an associated running thread). The code fails to do this in three places. In `Set`, one uses `std::thread`'s move-assignment to assign to the thread without regard to its previous contents. Calling `Set` multiple times without calling `Cancel` therefore is guaranteed to terminate. There is also no such call in the move-assignment operator or destructor of `Stopwatch`.

Second, because `Cancel` just calls `join`, it will wait for the timeout to happen and execute before returning, instead of canceling the timer. To cancel the timer, one must notify the thread. On the other end, the `Run` loop in the thread must have a way to be notified. The traditional way to do this is with a condition_variable.

For example:

```
class Stopwatch
{
public:
    Stopwatch() = default;

    Stopwatch(const Stopwatch&) = delete;
    Stopwatch(Stopwatch&&) = delete;
    Stopwatch& operator=(const Stopwatch&) = delete;
    Stopwatch& operator=(Stopwatch&& other) = delete;

    ~Stopwatch()
    {
        Cancel();
    }

    void Run(uint64_t ticks)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk{mutex_};
        cv_.wait_for(lk, std::chrono::milliseconds(ticks), [&] { return canceled_; });
        if (!canceled_)
            /* timeout code here */;
    }

    void Set(uint64_t ms)
    {
        Cancel();
        thread_ = std::thread(&Stopwatch::Run, this, ms);
    }

    void Cancel()
    {
        if (thread_.joinable())
        {
            {
                std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk{mutex_};
                canceled_ = true;
            }
            cv_.notify_one();
            thread_.join();
        }
    }

private:
    bool canceled_ = false;
    std::condition_variable cv_;
    std::mutex mutex_;
    std::thread thread_;
};
```